# Solaris let me in with different password with the same 8 first characters

Tags: solaris, password

I don't know if this is normal, but the thing is, let's say I have a  Solaris user called **gloaiza** and its password is **password2getin**

I'm logging into the server with PuTTY, I just put 192.168.224.100 and it prompts a windows asking for an user, so I type **gloaiza**, then it asks for a password and let's say I type **password2geti** by mistake, and *it worked!* I'm IN the server!

Is that normal? It also works if I put something like **password2getin2**.

*I'm not a native English speaker, so, in case there's something you can't understand please ask me*

OS: Oracle Solaris 10 1/13

Comment: What happens under eight characters? Does `passwork` get you in?

Comment: @thrig Ok, my actual password is 9 character long, so let's say the password is `pass2word`, then it works with `pass2wor`, `pass2word1`, `pass2worr1`, and so on...

I think it works with everything once you type `pass2wor`

I don't think it is a big problem, but isn't good either.

Comment: As long as you get the first 8 characters right, it will let you in. Unfortunately, generating a password has using encrypt in older solaris releases, disregards character 9 and afterwards.

Comment: Gentle reminder for all the embedded devs here thinking, "this could never happen on *my* system:" `busybox` will silently fall back to DES if you don't have all the right crypto options enabled in its `.config` **and** your `libc`. Maybe take a minute today to double-check your `passwd`/`shadow` files? ;)

Comment: @drewbenn - who the hell thought that *silently* degrading security is a good idea? Jesus Christ.

Comment: Afaict the problem is that "DES crypt" was the "historic default" and that support for newer stuff is seen as "features". So it's easy to inadvertantly do a build with those "features" disabled. The tools then use the best algorithm available and if the best available happens to be "DES crypt" then so be it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The operating system stores a [hash of the password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) in `/etc/shadow` (or, historically, `/etc/passwd`; or a different location on some other Unix variants). Historically, the first widespread password hash was a [DES-based scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Traditional_DES-based_scheme) which had the limitation that it only took into account the first 8 characters of the password. In addition, a password hashing algorithm needs to be slow; the DES-based scheme was somewhat slow when it was invented but is insufficient by today's standards.

Since then, better algorithms have been devised. But Solaris 10 defaults to the historical DES-based scheme. [Solaris 11](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1473/policy.conf-4.html) defaults to an algorithm based on iterated SHA-256 which is up to modern standards.

Unless you need historical compatibility with ancient systems, switch to the iterated SHA-256 scheme. Edit the file [`/etc/security/policy.conf`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5174/6mbb98uhs/index.html) and change the `CRYPT_DEFAULT` setting to 5 which stands for [`crypt_sha256`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5175/6mbba7evg/index.html). You may also want to set `CRYPT_ALGORITHMS_ALLOW` and `CRYPT_ALGORITHMS_DEPRECATE`.

Once you've changed the configuration, run `passwd` to change your password. This will update the password hash with the currently configured scheme.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When you said "_Unless you need historical compatibility with ancient systems_" you really mean it, what I mean is... Is it possible to really need the DES-based scheme, and not being able to change to SHA-256, for some reason?

Comment: @gloaiza You might if your password hash file is shared with NIS or some other method with a machine running a truly ancient operating system (like Solaris 2.x). Otherwise, no.

Comment: [Algorithm 2a (bcrypt) may be the best choice.](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/24065)

Answer (score 21):

This is expected, at least on a default Solaris 10 and older configuration.

Your system is using the legacy Unix `crypt_unix` algorithm which indeed limit the number of characters used to eight.

This is documented in the [`passwd` manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/passwd-1.html):

```
Passwords must be constructed to meet the following requirements:

  Each password must have PASSLENGTH characters, where PASSLENGTH is  defined  in
  /etc/default/passwd  and  is  set  to  6. Setting PASSLENGTH to more than eight
  characters requires configuring policy.conf(4) with an algorithm that  supports
  greater than eight characters.
```

As this algorithm is essentially obsolete. You should switch to something better (available values listed in the `crypt.conf` manual page) by setting the `CRYPT_ALGORITHMS_DEPRECATE` and `CRYPT_DEFAULT` entries the `/etc/security/policy.conf` file.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/concept-63/index.html

Comment: It is not true that "the higher the better". [Algorithm `2a` (bcrypt) may be the best](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/24065).

Comment: @OrangeDog Point taken, advice removed

Answer (score 7):

See [this thread on Oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1911506?start=0&tstart=0):

> The behavior you describe is expected when using the default
>   "crypt_unix" password encryption scheme. This scheme will only encrypt
>   the first eight characters of a password, and thus only the first
>   eight characters need to match when the password is typed in again. It
>   is not a "bug", but a known limitation of the algorithm - it is
>   largely kept around for backward compatibility, and unfortunately is
>   set as the default on Solaris systems when installed.
>
> To resolve this, set your OS to use MD5 or Blowfish algorithms instead
>   of crypt_unix.
>
> This can be changed in the /etc/security/policy.conf file. You can set
>   crypt algorithms to allow, and there is also a setting to deprecate
>   (forbid) the use of the "crypt_unix" algorithm and change the default
>   to a more secure one.
>
> See your "Solaris 10 System Administration Guide: Security Services"
>   for more information.

See also [Changing the Password Algorithm (Task Map)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/secsys-15/index.html) and especially [How to Specify an Algorithm for Password Encryption](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/secsys-20/index.html):

> Specify the identifier for your chosen encryption algorithm.
>
> ...
>
> Type the identifier as the value for the CRYPT_DEFAULT variable in the
>   /etc/security/policy.conf file.
>
> ...
>
> For more information on configuring the algorithm choices, see the `policy.conf(4)` man page.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, this also happens on IBM AIX systems up until version 7.1.

It's funny, because this system I worked with has a "cannot reuse any of the last 10 passwords" policy that *does* take into account the whole password lenght, but then only checks the first 8 characters when logging in. So you could set your passwords like `easypass_%$xZ!01`, `easypass_%&ssY!02`, `easypass_%$33zoi@@`, ... for every mandatory password change, effectively keeping `easypass` as your password for years.